# Slow smart group display on a contact after update to 5.46.3 from 5.35.x

Tags: smartgroups, performance

When viewing the group tab of a contact, there's a "smart groups" openable tab, which triggers an ajax call to

https://example.org/civicrm/contact/view/smartgroup?cid=youcontactid&snippet=json

After the security update of civicrm last week, two largish (100k+) installs are extremely slow when opening that tab.

One example is a query time of 1000 seconds to see if a contact is in a smart group that looks for all individual contacts with a primary email address.

Has anyone had any similar experiences?

Here's the slow sql:

```
mysqld, Version: 10.3.28-MariaDB-1:10.3.28+maria~focal (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time            Id Command  Argument
# Time: 220324 19:46:19
# User@Host: user @  [10.0.34.4]
# Thread_id: 46884  Schema: civicrm_db  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 1095.429051  Lock_time: 0.000378  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 800380665
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 629
use civicrm_db;
SET timestamp=1648151179;
SELECT      grp.id as group_id,
                        grp.title as title,
                        grp.frontend_title as frontend_title,
                        grp.frontend_description as frontend_description,
                        grp.description as description,
                        grp.saved_search_id as saved_search_id
            FROM        civicrm_group_en_US grp
            LEFT JOIN   civicrm_group_contact gc
                ON      gc.group_id = grp.id
            LEFT JOIN     civicrm_group_contact_cache gcc
                ON      gcc.group_id = grp.id
            WHERE       grp.is_hidden = 0
                        AND grp.id IN (298)
                AND     ((grp.saved_search_id is not null AND gcc.contact_id = 99609)
                            OR  (gc.contact_id = 99609
                                AND gc.status = 'Added')
                            
                        ) GROUP BY grp.id;
```

Comment: Likely https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3031

Comment: Yes, jamie's sql is exactly the one I'm seeing in my slow query log.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

As per Demerit's [link to the](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3031) existing issue, it's related to a recent change in CiviCRM core that tries to be smarter when presenting the unsubscribe form.

For non-obvious reasons, the changes to the sql scale badly.

I've submitted a PR that seems to improve my two sites, testing and comments welcomed.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23051

Comment: The PR has been merged into 5.48, thanks to you-know-who-you-are!